# How to run a ASP.NET Core Web API dll file as a service in Nginx server?

Tags: .net, ubuntu, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an **AWS EC2** instance running on **Ubuntu 16.04** server. I am running an **ASP.NET Core Web API** server in this instance.

I have followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) to host ASP.NET Core on Linux with `Nginx`. I have followed the tutorial until the `Monitoring the app` section. Now, i have run the web api dll file using below command and it is listening at `http://localhost:5000`

```
dotnet MyWebAPI.dll
```

I have run this above command by connecting with the EC2 instance using **PuTTY**. As i have set up the reverse proxy server, so i can hit my endpoint nicely using postman.

But, when i close the PuTTY session, the dll file is not running anymore. As a result, i could not hit the endpoint.

**So, what should i do to keep the dll file running on localhost as a service so that it does not stop when i close the PuTTY session?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could run my application as a service inside the `Nginx` server. Now, if i close the `PuTTY session`, the service is still running. I have used **systemd** to create a service file to start and monitor the underlying web app.

> systemd is an init system that provides many powerful features for
>   starting, stopping, and managing processes.

At first, i have created a service file for my web application

> sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/my-web-api.service

Then, inside that `my-web-api.service` file, i have included below configurations:

```
[Unit] 
Description=My first .NET Core application on Ubuntu 

[Service] 
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/MyWebAPI 
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/ubuntu/MyWebAPI/MyWebAPI.dll 
Restart=always 
RestartSec=10 # Restart service after 10 seconds if dotnet service crashes 
SyslogIdentifier=offershare-web-app
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, i need to enable the service and run it.

```
sudo systemctl enable my-web-api.service
sudo systemctl start my-web-api.service
sudo systemctl status my-web-api.service
```

Now, the status command should show the service as running if the configuration is correct. Now, my web application is running, kestrel by default listens on port **5000**, so my application is available on **http://localhost:5000**.

**Now, if i close the PuTTY session, my web api is still running.**

Answer (score 1):

*Posting on behalf of [@Brudex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1969677/brudex) (this was edited into the question, instead of being posted as an answer - happy to delete this copy if original author posts this him/her-self correctly as an answer)*

---

You have to use a process manager like supervisor to keep the asp.net file running. Use nginx as a reverse proxy to forward request to your asp.net core application.

Follow to install and setup supervisor to manage ur asp.net apps

1. sudo `apt-get install supervisor`
2. create a supervisor config like follows

   ```
   [program:hellomvc]
   command=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/aspnetcore/HelloMVC/HelloMVC.dll
   directory=/var/aspnetcore/HelloMVC/
   autostart=true
   autorestart=true
   stderr_logfile=/var/log/hellomvc.err.log
   stdout_logfile=/var/log/hellomvc.out.log
   environment=HOME=/var/www/,ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
   user=www-data
   stopsignal=INT
   stopasgroup=true
   killasgroup=true
   ```
3. Start supervisor with

   ```
   sudo service supervisor start
   ```

You can find more information from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx